# Find a function discontinuous everywhere but $\ x = 0$

Tags: limits, functions, continuity

Find a function discontinuous everywhere but $\ x = 0$
After considering modifications to the Dirichlet function however I have not got anywhere. Is there a method to find such function or is it purely intuition with a bit of creativity?

Comment: The $\delta$-function isn't actually a function, it's a distribution, but I think it's still a neat example: $\frac{1}{\delta(x)}$.

Answer (score 2):

$f: \Bbb R \to \Bbb R$ defined by:
$$f(x) = \begin{cases} x & x \in \Bbb Q\\
                       -x & x \in \Bbb R\setminus \Bbb Q\\
\end{cases}$$

is only continuous at $x=0$ (source "counterexamples in analysis" p. 22)